# RewriteRule gives 404

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have troubles with mod_rewrite.

I have wordpress site located in 'wp' directory. It is accessible as `http://localhost/wp/`

There is page `http://localhost/wp/sample-page/` on the site.

I want to make this page open with url `http://localhost/wp/sample-page-2/` without redirect.

Here is what in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^sample-page-2/$ sample-page/ [L]
```

But I'm getting 404 error.

Could somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

@soju: Well, "sample-page-2" - is just example

1. It is not a page/post in worpress sence.
2. Actually I tried to add one section to the url. E.g. `http://localhost/wp/sample-page/section/`. And this rule `RewriteRule ^sample-page/section/$ sample-page/ [L]` didn't work. Then I decided to "simpliyfy" url("sample-page-2" instead of "sample-page/section") - no success.

**UPD2**

BTW, redirect `RewriteRule ^sample-page-2/$ sample-page/ [R=301,L]` works

Comment: Why not simply modify page slug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose wordpress rewrite rules are after your own rule, so you should remove `[L]` option to let wordpress handle `sample-page` url

**EDIT about UPD2** : Well, it works with a 301 redirection, but you said you don't want redirection ?

You can add a filter on `rewrite_rules_array` to make your own rewrite rule, take a look at example on codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples

Comment: Yep, I don't need redirect. I was wondering why redirect to wp page works and rewrite - doesn't. Direct url input is pasred correctly, and rewrited url - wrong. It must be wordpress "feature":) Thanks anyway, I'll check WP_Rewrite. Thx.